# StringFormat on Combobox Displaymemberpath

Tags: wpf, combobox, string-formatting

I am trying to use StringFormat on DisplayMemberPath property of a ComboBox (WPF). But i don't know even if this is possible. can someone help me with some ideas.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
  <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Path=MyDateField, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}}" Name="CmbName" Width="120" />
```

But it isn't working...

Thx All

Comment: I upvoted since I am also interested in the solution. I think you need a converter but I'm not sure.

Comment: yeah, i think i will need a converter too, but i created this post first to try a "cleaner" solution :D

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can simply use the `ItemStringFormat` property.

**Note:** This works only if `IsEditable` is set to `False`

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding YourItems}"
          DisplayMemberPath="MyDateField"
          ItemStringFormat="{}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"
          IsEditable="False" />
```

Comment: @DiegoVieira no probs, this solution works only if IsEditable="False"

Comment: It also works in <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>  <Style TargetType="ComboBox"> <Setter Property="ItemStringFormat" Value="{}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"/>

Comment: if IsEditable="True" then it does not work for the displayed item but works when you open the ComboBox