# Combobox binding and stringFormat

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have a WPF Combobox

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=Ctrl, Path=Day, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat='00'}"
ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Ctrl, Path=AvailableDays, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat='00'}"
IsEditable="True" Grid.Column="0" />
```

which is Databound to these Properties

```
public int? Day {
    get { return _day; }
    set {
        if (_day != value) {
            _day = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

public IEnumerable<int> AvailableDays {
    get { return _availableDays ?? (_availableDays = Enumerable.Range(1, 31)); }
}
```

Binding works. But my issue is the Formating of the values. I want days<10 to be formated with a leading zero. But my "StringFormat='00'" is completly ignored, which is odd because the same format works with a textblock without a problem.

Comment: Have you tried setting `ItemStringFormat="00"` on the `ComboBox`?

Comment: I've read somewhere that it should work only if `IsEditable="False"` on your `ComboBox`. So in your case, it shouldn't work. But give it a try anyway.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533986/stringformat-on-combobox-displaymemberpath

Comment: @SuperOli: It is just as you said. ItemStringFormat works for all DropDown-Items. It only works for the selected Item if `IsEditable="False"`. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Binding.StringFormat` works only if target property type is `string`. This is why it works with `string TextBlock.Text`, but doesn't work with `object ComboBox.SelectedValue`. Generally, if you want to format the result of a binding, you can create a custom `StringFormatConverter : IValueConverter` class with trivial implementation and use it in `Binding.Converter`.

In your case, you should use `ComboBox.ItemStringFormat` instead.