# How to Add especial character in the midle of the word, after get the text of combobox in C#?

Tags: c#

I have my comboBox, and the user will write something there.

I use (mycomboBox.text = "01465650912"), to past the text into my combobox.

The problem is that, I want to add a especial character like this:

**[01-4-6565-09-12]**

I want to add a hyphen, after the 2 character, after the third and so on in all the place that i have the hyphen.

My logic is: first I have to read, after that, I have to count how many character is there. next, I have to say something like: if is character 2, catenate with "-" if is character 4 catenate with"-" and so on.

I have restrict the combobox to write only 15 character include hyphen

Could Somenone explain to me how?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure if the result is a typo because it went from "my string is here" to "my-s-thing-is-here" but it *almost* looks like you want to do a [string Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.7.2) on spaces -- `string str = "my string is here"; str.Replace(' ', '-'); `.

Comment: No I dont want to replace on spaces, I want to add a hyphen in the string. I will edit the context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `string.Insert` function can be used to insert characters at desired positions:

```
string source = "01465650912";
string output = source.Insert(2, "-").Insert(4, "-").Insert(9, "-").Insert(12, "-");
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Output:

```
01-4-6565-09-12
```

Comment: The problem is that, this don't work when we don't know what user had write.
Imagine that you don't know what user write. what would you do?

Comment: @BráulioJoelson Put whatever the user wrote into source. What's the problem? `source = myComboBox.text`

Comment: how do I divide? 

String output  =  source.Insert( ?,  "-").Insert( ?,  "-")

What i write in "?" if you don't know the numbers

Comment: Thank you @BlueMonkMN. I tried your solution like you said, it works like I want. 

         string source = "01465650912";
         

string output = source.Insert(2, "-").Insert(4, "-").Insert(9, "-").Insert(12, "- 
         ");

Thank's

Comment: this will fail if the source length is short

Answer (score 3):

You just want to format it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.combobox.format

> 01-4-6565-09-12

[Format string with dashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968845/format-string-with-dashes)

```
String.Format("{0:##-#-####-##-##}")
```

as found here: [StringFormat on Combobox Displaymemberpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533986/stringformat-on-combobox-displaymemberpath)

```
ItemStringFormat="{}{0:##-#-####-##-##}"
```

**edit** or mask it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.combobox.inputmask 
`InputMask`

Comment: The problem is that, this don't work when we don't know what user had write. Imagine that you don't know what user write. what would you do?

Comment: Mask the input?

Comment: @BráulioJoelson you haven't told us what should happen if the user inputs any other length of string...

Comment: obviously the world would come to an end ;) http://weknowmemes.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/its-the-end-of-the-world-not-the-moon.jpg

Comment: if the user put more than 15 character, combobox will just keep with the 15

Comment: I am trying  this "Format string with dashes"